# When do you choose the spell for the Prodigy move?

Tags: spells, dungeon-world, moves

The description of the Prodigy move reads:

> Choose a spell. You prepare that spell as if it were one level lower.

Is this spell chosen when you get the move? Or can you change this choice each time you setup your spells?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The spell is chosen when you get the move.

A move that activated when you prepare spells would say "when you prepare spells" - The Wizard has no stock moves that work like this, but The Cleric's Divine Intervention/Invincibility have a similar trigger: "when you commune".

**Because there is no precondition, the choice happens once, when you take the move.** This makes The Wizard's choice of prodigy/mastery expressive of The Wizard's approach to magic, whatever that may be - contrast with the more simply worded "you may prepare one additional level of spells."

It's very difficult to find a rules cite to prove a negative, but if you'd care for a parallel case, grab The Fighter's playbook and have a look at Iron Hide: "you gain +1 armor". How many times do you think that's supposed to happen?

Though, to be fair, Fightgar's pretty much always getting use out of +1 armor. If Wizzrobe isn't getting the chance to prep the spell they're a prodigy at/master of, then even though the choice is only **intended** to be made once, maybe they should get together with the GM to work out how to change the rules.